# Add context menu based on multiple selection of project items across solution using visual studio addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I have been working on visual studio Add-in for quiet some time.

I need to add context menu for project item. This can done as follows.

```
CommandBar vsBarItem = cmdBars["Item"]; //the pop up for clicking a project Item
```

This context menu is visible only on the single/multiple selection of project items inside a single project selection.

Is there a way to add context menu for selection of multiple project items inside the solution ( irrespective of the project being selected). To be more precise, for ex

I have 2 projects in solution namely Project A and project B.
If Project A contains projectItem1, ProjectItem2  and
If Project B contains projectItem3, projectItem4.

I need a context menu when I select ProjectItem1 and ProjectItem4.

References:

I tried all the below options but in vain :(

```
CommandBar vsBarMultipleSelection = cmdBars["Multi-Select"];
CommandBar vsBarMultipleSelection = cmdBars["Multiple selections"];
```

Please let me know which item of commandBar API should I use, so that I will have context menu for multiple selection.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Carlos from Microsoft forum.

My question is answered in the link below. It might help others who are looking for the same.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68daca69-5b8c-4437-b73e-a9a3203cb683/add-context-menu-based-on-multiple-selection-of-project-items-across-solution-using-visual-studio?forum=vsx